# How to create a flow in runtime in mule 4

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

I want to create a new mule flow in runtime based on a flow-template. I found that Java module in mule 4 may help me with this, so in my main flow, I tried to invoke Java instance method:

```
<http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="5b0f79ff-1a60-4c1a-bc9d-fbe350f4e595" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/producer"/>

<java:new doc:name="New DynamicProducerFlowGenerator" doc:id="6c8cf087-0601-4b89-9d24-16650b9a6e6f" class="DynamicProducerFlowGenerator" constructor="DynamicProducerFlowGenerator()" target="DynamicProducerFlowGenerator"/>

<java:invoke doc:name="Invoke" doc:id="d5258c18-74e8-4c86-a0ae-758ad41d1b32" instance="#[vars.DynamicProducerFlowGenerator]" class="DynamicProducerFlowGenerator" method="initialise()"/>
```

To invoke this method, I created a Java class called DynamicProducerFlowGenerator, this is my Java code:

public class DynamicProducerFlowGenerator {

```
public DynamicProducerFlowGenerator() {

}



    public void initialise() {

            MuleContextFactory muleContextFactory = new DefaultMuleContextFactory();                



    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder("dynamic-producer-flow-template.xml");

            

    MuleContext muleContext = muleContextFactory.createMuleContext();

    builder.configure(muleContext);

    muleContext.start();

    }
```

}

However, when I tried to run this, I always got a error:

```
Message        : Invocation of Method 'initialise()' from Class 'DynamicProducerFlowGenerator' without any argument resulted in an error.

Cause: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException - Couldn't find config via SPI mechanism. Corrupted Mule core jar?
```

I think the problem lies in this line of code

"MuleContext muleContext = muleContextFactory.createMuleContext();"

But I do not know how to solve it. This is my some of  dependencies in pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>

  <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>

  <artifactId>mule-devkit-annotations</artifactId>

  <version>3.9.7</version>

  <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>

    <groupId>org.mule</groupId>

    <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>

    <version>3.9.0</version>

</dependency>

    <dependency>

  <groupId>org.mule.module</groupId>

  <artifactId>mule-java-module</artifactId>

  <version>1.2.6</version>

  <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>

</dependency>

<dependency>

    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>

    <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>

    <version>3.9.0</version>
```

Could anyone help me with this? Is there another way that I can use to create a new flow in runtime in mule 4?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, your dependencies seem be mixing Mule 3 and Mule 4 dependencies. That will never work, they are incompatible. For example Devkit is a Mule 3 tool. If you are using a method intended for Mule 3, as it appears to be the case in your example, it will not work when used in Mule 3.

Secondly, I would ask what problem are you trying to resolve by creating flows dynamically. I'm not sure they are supported in Mule 4. I don't think it is good practice. Calling anything from the mule-core or similar Mule libraries inside a Java component is not a good practice for sure. For example accessing the Mule Context [is not a good practice even in a connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/general-coding-rules#dont-access-the-mulecontext).

I advise to define exactly what you need to achieve and try alternative methods that are better supported and recommended. For example, using the [XML SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/xml-sdk), to create parametrized 'connectors' from flows, or [Java SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/) to create connectors and modules in Java.